# Diophantine Equations - 4th Powers / Computational Number Theory

Tags: number-theory, diophantine-equations

I  am looking for two integers, a and b , which when raised to the fourth power and added together equal  either  $115723683465520156810$,  or  $115712970354183898410$ , or  $115734396970441439210$.

Thus $(a^4) + (b^4) = 115723683465520156810$
or   $(a^4) + (b^4) =  115712970354183898410$
or   $(a^4) + (b^4) =  115734396970441439210 $

Can anyone give me a  software program to  check whether an integer is the sum of two  fourth  powers?

Comment: Your three numbers are divisible by $7$, $3$, and $23$, respectively, but not by the squares of those primes, each of which is congruent to $3$ mod $4$.  They are consequently not expressible as a sum of two *squares*, much less two fourth powers.

Answer (score 1):

None of those equations are possible.

Suppose $a^4 + b^4 = n$ where $n$ is one of the three numbers

$$115723683465520156810,\;\;115712970354183898410,\;\;115734396970441439210$$

If either of $a,b$ is a multiple of $5$, then, since $n$ is a multiple of $5$, it follows that $a,b$ must both be multiples of $5$. But then $a^4+b^4$ would be a multiple of $5^4$, contradiction, since $n$ is a not a multiple of $25$.
Thus, neither of $a,b$ is a multiple of $5$. But then
\begin{align*}
&a^4 + b^4 = n\\[6pt]
\implies\; &a^4 + b^4 \equiv 0 \pmod{5}\qquad\text{[since $n$ is a multiple of $5$]}\\[6pt]
\implies\; &1 + 1 \equiv 0 \pmod{5}\qquad\;\;\;\text{[by Fermat's little Theorem]}\\[6pt]
\implies\; &2 \equiv 0 \pmod{5}\\[6pt]
\end{align*}

contradiction.